# Generating SQL Server Views from EDMX using T4 templates

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm working with a legacy database that I can't easily create an entity model over because it uses extension tables with what is effectively composite keys and EF only supports single column keys for mapping one entity to multiple tables.

So, what I've decided to do is create updatable views (with `INSTEAD OF` triggers to handle CRUD operations) over the top of the legacy tables (which cannot be touched) and then have my entity model (either using EF or DevExpress XPO) built on top of the database views. This will also allow me to do stuff like easily add sub-queries in the select clause to retrieve child counts on parent records when retrieving a list of parent records in a single query.

However, I don't particularly want to manually write the SQL for all the views and triggers so I thought I'd use data model defined in the `.EDMX` file and t4 templates to help me generate the bulk of the T-SQL needed to create the views and the triggers. I thought there would be some template that I could use as the basis for doing this, but seems that's not so easy to find.

Can someone please suggest a t4 template that I could use as the basis where mappings are being retrieved from the `.EDMX`. Alternatively can anyone advise how to use the `StorageMappingItemCollection` to retrieve the mapping information from the EDMX file. I know a few people have said that apparently you can't use it or that they just use Linq to Xml, but I would have thought it should certainly be possible to use the `StorageMappingItemCollection` class as a strongly typed class to access this data.

Any examples of how I could use `StorageMappingItemCollection` to access mapping info would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Is there seriously nobody who has ever tried to generate views from an EDMX file in the past?  From what little information I can find on the web it seems StorageMappingItemCollection is pretty useless and LinqToEdmx seems like an option or LinqToXml to query the EDMX directly.

Answer (score 0):

See http://brewdawg.github.io/Tiraggo.Edmx/ you can install it via NuGet within Visual Studio and it serves up all of the metadata from your EDMX files that Microsoft hides from you, very simple, works great.